# What is the best way to say "Thank you" to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I recently passed a Microsoft certification exam and want to thank the Stack Overflow community for awesome answers and questions that actually helped me prepare for the exam and pass it.

How can I do this?

Comment: Vote up the questions and answers that helped you.

Comment: You can buy a small symbolic gift for the community. For example a cruise ship :)

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Build a shrine to Jon Skeet

Answer (score 6):

1. Make sure you up-voted and always accepted an answer to all your questions
2. Pay it back.
     -- Find suitable (for StackOverflow*) questions to answer and answer them **well**.
     -- Get enough rep that way to help run the place with editing questions to improve them, review effort etc.

`*` ... and this has the subtask: learn, refresh yourself etc on what is suitable.

Comment: Downvoted for "Find questions to answer and answer them" - this totally needs a disclaimer that one shouldn't just answer every piece of crap that ends up on SO just because it's possible to do so. Answering copypasted homework assignments with "try this [code dump]" is actively harmful; thus a blanket statement like "answer everything you can" is harmful as well.

Comment: @l4mpi Corrected to be explicit on this point.   Thanks for explaining your downvote.

Comment: That's not exactly what I meant - writing a decent answer to a really really bad question is still harmful.

Comment: Further explication.

Answer (score 2):

Continue to vote up the questions and answers that helped you.

Answer questions that you can, and believe you should. Improve or Downvote content that needs to be improved.

Work through the review queue when you access it.

Continue to use the site to give future developers the benefit of your experience.

Comment: Oh, and upvote other people's answers when they answer well too ;)

Comment: And good comments.

Comment: As I commented on GreenAsJades answer, "Answer questions that you can" definitely needs a disclaimer that not all questions should be answered.

Comment: Don't forego downvoting where appropriate. Far too few people do that, because they want to be "nice".

Answer (score 1):

- Perform meaningful edits to posts
- Provide help to other members within your area of now, certified expertise (congratulations by the way!)