# How can we educate others to pay it forward instead of leaving thanks comments?

Tags: feature-request

I'm troubled by much of the recent post on the SO blog. Regardless of the various viewpoints on the crux of the post, I think it hit one point that might be an easy win that nearly everyone could gain from. That point is that gratitude ("Thanks", "You helped me too!") isn't something that the current SO design handles well. As is mentioned elsewhere, thanks-only comments add noise and can attract other noise (which makes this one of the few situations in life where a large number of grateful people is actually a problem!)

So embedding thanks into a question is a noisy, and thanks-only comments are also (typically) noisy. However, I think we could change the perceived tone of the SO community in a more welcoming direction for new users and perhaps others with some non-noisy way to express gratitude.

One idea that might work would be to detect comments that are thanks-only, and notify the (presumably new) user that such a comment isn't a great fit for the [site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment) but then give them a suggested way to pay it forward. An example of this could be guiding them to a help page about editing posts to improve grammar or fix formatting. A way to sweeten the deal for a newcomer would be to give out a one-time bronze badge for following up on a "pay-it-forward" prompt within X hours or something.

It isn't that Stack Overflow doesn't welcome gratitude. It is that Stack Overflow's very structure relies upon continual good-will, which I argue is often a form of gratitude: Nearly everything done on the site is performed by volunteers that don't get any direct renumeration for their time. Newcomers might not understand this nuance, but without much effort, perhaps we can help them understand it and join without quite as much confusion.

Comment: Your question may have been answered before under [What is the best way to say "Thank you" to Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294902/what-is-the-best-way-to-say-thank-you-to-stack-overflow) (and duplicates thereof).

Comment: @usr2564301 I agree these are similar. However, this is actually a feature-request with a proposed solution that involves education. I think this stands on its own.

Comment: But the answers in the duplicate still apply -- up-votes and accept votes are the best ways to thank the members of the site for their answers and questions.

Comment: Yes. So the question here is "is <proposal above> a good way to explicitly teach others about how to do <answers you've mentioned>?"

Comment: Ah – the meta questions were exactly because users *do not know*.

Comment: meh. How much benefit will this truly bring?

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter I don't know. It seemed like low-hanging fruit that wouldn't offend any particular group. I haven't seen results from discussions about that post accomplishing even that much.

Comment: Is it really a problem? I often receive "thank you" comments (in various forms) on my answers (typically from question asker) but I didn't ever see anyone bothered by that or tell commenter that it's discouraged (I don't bother either).

Comment: @Evk: I add a comment if I come accross an explicit "thx it worked" on an unaccepted answer from an obvious new user, pointing them towards "Help! Somebody answered my question!" in the Help.

Comment: @usr2564301 well that confirms my point if you only do that in mentioned conditions and don't bother otherwise. By that you encourage that person to accept answer instead of _just_ leaving comment, that's a good thing. I talk mostly about "noise" part. It seems to me, people often leave those comments and no one is bothered, already.

Comment: @Evk that's an interesting point. If it isn't noise _to almost anyone_ it should be encouraged, not prohibited by site rules on meta and faqs. However, I'm not yet convinced that is the opinion of the majority.

Comment: No, it's not *not* annoying – just not enough to go through the daily front page and compulsively flag every single one of them. Too many, to relieve too little irritation. All those "Unnecessary or otherwise no longer needed" flags have to get handled by the mods, too. It'd be something else if we could honestly flag them as "rude" (as in "clearly not according to community guidelines"), because these *do* get automatically deleted when they get a certain number of flags.

Comment: Whenever I answer a question and get a "Thank you" comment from the OP, I just leave this comment: "[Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)". Usually, they get the picture.

Comment: @ZoharPeled That's pretty cool. Supposing this idea isn't implemented in any form, I'm going to start doing what you do.

Comment: If this is about the "thanks" in questions, perhaps there could be automatic edit descriptions that can be easily selected (similar to the [AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) userscript). As it is, the most likely description seen for removing "thanks" is "removed thanks", which doesn't do a good job explaining why it is being removed. It takes too much time/effort to expect the editors to form a full description explaining why, or linking.

Comment: cross site duplicate https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177292/comments-saying-thank-you-remind-op-to-accept-answer

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Very similar, but doesn't point users to pay-it-forward activities like editing. That said, maybe I should've asked this there? I've *never* figured out when to post there.

Comment: @Justin: There are a couple different scripts on StackApps for the purpose; I use [SOX](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox)'s feature for the purpose, which is pretty efficient. (Although my relevant edit reason isn't all that amazing: I just put in "blew away fluff".)

Comment: @ZoharPeled see. Besides the helpful link that's both fluff and humor, two things currently on the no-no list. Yet it is **really** effective and you should keep doing it. Seeing some environmental changes that makes such a comment just expected and accepted behavior is fine by me, and that is one thing I see the blog post putting on the radar.

Comment: @Gimby I'm all about rules and standards, when they make sense. However, I've always thought that "no please, no thank you" is a stupid rule. If someone comments in my answer with a "thank you" comment, and also accept it (or at least accept another answer), maybe even upvote it, I just replay "Glad to help :-)" (without the link). Personally I think that's just plain courtesy. I know that the "strict" policy is against such comments, but I think this policy  is a part of the problem that leads people to think of the Stackoverflow community as a hostile environment.

Comment: @ZoharPeled precisely. We're simply not machines, so lets stop pretending basic social interaction is fluff. We need to use it and use it well or else we just keep sending each other the wrong signals. Its like a cat that can't move it's tail. The cat can mean well, the other cats have no way of really knowing it and so will likely react to it defensively.

Comment: ... Now imagine that going on for another 50-or so lines, if a post is deemed so useful everyone-and-his-neighbour wants to add his explicit thanks. That's why I consider *one* thankyou as unnecessary-but-not-flagworthy, but piles upon piles... no thanks.

Comment: @usr2564301 Oh, I absolutely agree comments like "thanks" and "me too" from users unrelated to the post shouldn't be encouraged. That's why you can [protect questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) once you have 15k rep. But that's different then getting a "thank you" or "you're welcome" from the poster  of the question/answer. I see lots of posts where the OP is upvoting, accepting and also writes a "thank you" comment. I think it's kinda rude to ignore that, even worst to automatically delete it. I'd rather just post a "Glad to help" with a friendly smile.

Comment: Why does it matter? if they are showing gratitude then they will likely contribute more later anyways.

Comment: @JGallardo perhaps. I guess it avoids a potential situation where someone says "thanks" and then gets told not to thank people, and feels hurt, unnecessarily. Again, I'm imagining this as a small gain, but also a non-contentious and low-cost one.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I wish I could get SOX working.... its options just straight up don't appear for me. :-( I've left an issue on the github repo, but so far have had no response